# Body content filter rejects posts with Chinese characters, but with a wrong error message

Tags: bug, quality-filter, specific-edit, internationalization

After migrating a question to Stack Overflow ([Using a covering index to select records for a certain day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34283719)), I attempted to make some edits, but found I could not save the text.

Specifically, the error was:

[image: Body cannot contain "I would li".]

Of course, that sounds like a silly content restriction.  It turns out that no matter what text the question starts with, the content filter will reject it.

The *real* trigger for the rejection is the Chinese characters further down:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `weixin_kol_status` (
>   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `url` varchar(512) NOT NULL COMMENT '微信连接',
>   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT '发表时间',
>   `title` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '标题',
>   `text` text COMMENT '发表内容',
>   `attitudes_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '点赞数',
>   `readcount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '阅读数',
>   `reposts_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '转发数',
>   `comments_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '评论数',
>   `userid` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT '发表者微信号',
>   `screen_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT '发表者名称',
>   `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '正负面1/-1/0',
>   `ext_data` text COMMENT '扩展数据，content_tag内容标签',
>   `is_topline` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '是否头条',
>   `is_business` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '是否商业微博',
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>   UNIQUE KEY `idx_url` (`url`(255)),
>   KEY `idx_userid` (`userid`),
>   KEY `idx_name` (`screen_name`),
>   KEY `idx_created_at` (`created_at`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=328727437 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
> ```

After some experimentation, I found that if I delete all of the Chinese comments, then I can save the edit successfully.

Is the prohibition on Chinese characters intentional?  If so (and I hope it isn't), please fix the error message to state the true cause of the rejection.  If it is unintentional, then please fix the body content filter.

Comment: Bug has been reproduced on Safari 9 on OS X, as well as Mobile Safari on iOS 9.2 (both the mobile and full desktop interface).

Comment: I think a pretty blunt Chinese filter was implemented on some sites to combat a rather nasty rash of SPAM, so the rejection was intentional at some point at least. (Reject message is confusing indeed though.)

Comment: On Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263724/unable-to-post-chinese-characters-due-to-validation-filter

Comment: @JanDoggen Interesting. How did it get posted to Code Review in the first place, then? (That's what made me assume that this was a Stack Overflow-specific bug.)